# How to get number of installed apps in android in JAVA

Tags: java, android

I want to get number of total apps in android and make sure that this is not working.

```
int numberOfInstalledApps = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0).size();
```

This always returns 138,
If I uninstall a app then returns 138
If I download an app then returns 138.

Comment: I got solution, add permission

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />

in android 11

Comment: If you find the solution yourself, you're encouraged to just post it to an answer to your own question. Posting it as a comment isn't quite as useful.

Answer (score 1):

To get the non-system applications installed on the device, you can do the following :

```
public static ArrayList<String> getAllInstalledApps() {

        ArrayList<String> applicationsList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<PackageInfo> packageList = getPackageManager()
             .getInstalledPackages(0);

        for (int i=0; i < packageList.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo packInfo = packageList.get(i);

            if ((packInfo.applicationInfo.flags 
                & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {

                String applicationName = packInfo.applicationInfo
                       .loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();

                applicationsList.add(applicationName);
                Log.e("App >" + Integer.toString(i), applicationName);
            }
        }
        return applicationsList;
    }
```

You can then get the list by doing:

```
int number = getInstalledApps().size();
```

You can also start any of the applications by calling:

```
Intent callAppIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
callAppIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List appsList = context.getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(callAppIntent, 0);
```